# d3 update tooltip in a separate function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Due to the complexity of my program, I am mocking up an easier version. The goal here is to click on the switch button and toggle the tooltip text between scaled coordinates and actual coordinates. In the `update()` function, I have no idea how to associate actual values to the `d` element in `svg`. Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .tooltip {
            position: absolute;
            pointer-events: none;
            z-index: 10;
            background: #dddddd;
            font: sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
            opacity: 0;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
            border-radius: 8px;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function update() {
            /* Need help here */
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id=switchButton>
        <button id=switch onclick="update()">Switch</button>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div id=scatterDiv></div>

    <script>
        var width = 800,
            height = 800;

        var randomX = [],
            randomY = [];
        for (var i = 0; i <= 25; i++) {
            randomX[i] = Math.random() * 400;
            randomY[i] = Math.random() * 400;
        }

        var x = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([d3.min(randomX) - 20, d3.max(randomX) + 20])
            .range([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([d3.min(randomY) - 20, d3.max(randomY) + 20])
            .range([height, 0]);

        var svg = d3.selectAll("#scatterDiv").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

        var tooltip = d3.select("#scatterDiv").append("div").attr("class", "tooltip");

        svg.append("g").selectAll("dot")
            .data(randomY)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("cy", function (d) {
                return y(d);
            })
            .attr("cx", function (d, i) {
                return x(randomX[i]);
            })
            .style("fill", "brown")
            .attr("r", 6)
            .on("mouseover", function (d) {
                tooltip.style("opacity", 1);
                var tooltipText = "";
                tooltipText += "(" + d3.select(this).attr("cx") + ", " + d3.select(this).attr("cy") + ")";
                tooltip.html(tooltipText)
                    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 20) + "px")
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 40) + "px");
            })
            .on("mouseout", function (d) {
                tooltip.style("opacity", 0);
            });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So in one version you're passing the values through the scales and in the other one you don't?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Yes. One version is `(x(randomX[i]), y(d))`, while the other version is `(d.randomX, d.randomY)`.

Comment: Then all you need to do is check which state you're in when setting the tooltip text and use one or the other.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff How can I link the `update()` function to the actual point that has the mouseover event? Somehow the `d` element is lost outside `.on("mouseover", function(d){ ... })`.

Comment: You don't need to. Have a global variable that you set in `update()` and check when setting the content.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff If I get this right, do you mean creating tooltip texts in `.on("mouseover", function(d){ ... })` using `if`, `else` condition, and `update()` is only used for setting state for switching status?

Comment: Yes. There are other ways to do it of course.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thanks for the suggestion. My actual program is a lot more complicated than this. Instead of toggling tooltips, I have to change tooltips dynamically based on user interaction. In addition, I also want to avoid adding more global variables just to keep things cleaner. However, I think your suggestion might be the easiest way to solve the problem. Thanks again! I will play around with it.